# Escaner de codigo qr zxing

Tags: android, android-studio, qrcode, zxing

Buenas estoy intentando hacer un lector de codigos qr pero al iniciar el escaner se muestra como un lector de codigo de barras.

Estas son las propiedades de mi escaner

```
private fun initScanner() {
        val integrator = IntentIntegrator(this@InicioActivity)
        integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE)
        integrator.setPrompt("Escaneé el código QR")
        integrator.setBeepEnabled(true)
        integrator.initiateScan()
    }
```

Como se ve le digo que sea un qr.code pero lo ignora

Muchas gracias